# Existe alguma forma forçar a sobrescrita do stash em cima das modificações atuais?

Tags: git

Quando eu uso o comando `git stash` para esconder as alterações, ocorre de as vezes precisar de alterar esse mesmo arquivo, enquanto o mesmo já está escondido pelo Stash.

Quando eu tento aplicar um `git stash pop`, mas ao mesmo tempo um dos arquivos que está guardado pelo stash tem uma modificação no ramo atual, aparece uma mensagem de erro, informando sobre esta modificação.

Fiz um pequeno código como exemplo abaixo

Exemplo:

```
>> mkdir test_repo 

>> cd test_repo

>> git init

>> echo "Arquivo A" > a.txt

>> git add a.txt

>>git commit -m "Criando o arquivo A"

>> echo "Arquivo A modificado para fazer um teste com Stash" > a.txt
git stash

>> echo "Arquivo A modificado mais uma vez" > a.txt

>> git stash pop
```

Quando faço isso, o seguinte erro é emitido:

> erro: As alterações locais dos seguintes arquivos serão substituídas durante a mesclagem: a.txt.
>
> Confirme suas alterações ou aguarde-as antes de mesclar. Abortando

Existe alguma maneira  de forçar que o `git stash pop` sobrescreva o arquivo no trabalho atual, independente de ele ter modificações ou não?

Comment: Já tentou `git stash apply`?

Comment: Se você quiser sobreescrever de fato os arquivos, poderia usar o `git checkout stash -- .`, não? O que fariam os arquivos da tua branch, no diretório corrente, ficar na versão do stash...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar essa segunda opção funciona, a primeira não obtive sucesso ao tentar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sobreescrever os arquivos com o que está no stash, é necessário realizar um `checkout` com os arquivos do stash, para isso, basta utilizar o comando:

```
git checkout stash -- .
```

Esse comando pegará **todos** os commits do stash, conforme comentário do @[Wallace Maxsters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters), é possível escolher apenas um dos commits do stash, para isso, basta listar os commits com:

```
git stash list
```

e selecionar o seu alvo, como exemplifica o comando a seguir para o commit recente do stash:

```
git checkout stash{0} -- .
```

---

Caso você queira *megear* os arquivos, você pode utilizar:

```
git merge --squash stash
```

Isso pegará **todos os commits** que estão no stash e começará o processo de merge com o branch corrente.

Caso você queira apenas sobreescrever os arquivos que estão no stash e manter as modificações feitas no branch atual, é necessário adicionar a opção de resolução de merge `--strategy-option=theirs`, ficando o comando da seguinte forma:

```
git merge --squash --strategy-option=theirs stash
```

---

É importante lembrar que isso não limpa o seu stash, para remover a última entrar é necessário utilizar o `git stash drop`.

Comment: Importante a última observação. O `git stash pop` costuma remover o stash aplicado (pelo menos comigo, quando há conflitos ele fica armazenado ainda, mesmo com o `pop`).

Comment: **Observação**: Seria legal incluir na sua resposta que tem como fazer o checkout de um Stash específico (porque você pode ter vários). No caso, usando `git checkout stash@{0} -- file.txt`. O `0` é o stash mais recente.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, editei a resposta. (: